# How to make Javascript Reload without refresh

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

I would like to know if it is possible to reload the Javascript in a page without refreshing the whole thing, thus losing the edited Css elements.

My scenario:

I'm editing an highly dynamic slider, and every element has to be carefully positioned. I only have one element into the hypothetical sliders's array, and once the animation for that single slider ends, there's no way to see the changes I've made taking action.

I know I can hardcode into the html another slider, so they'll keep going forever, yet I'd be more intrigued in some sort of console solution.

Any clue?

Comment: Show us some code, so we can understand better what you are asking and try to help.

Comment: Why not just put an initial state of your javascript elements into a function on page load and call that function when you want to "refresh"

Answer (score 0):

You could load a new script with a function, let's say it's called loadJS:

```
function loadJS(script)
{
    var docHeadObj = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var dynamicScript = document.createElement("script");
    dynamicScript.type = "text/javascript";
    dynamicScript.src = scriptName;
    docHeadObj.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

So whenever you want to 'reload' the script, you can execute the function, for example: `loadJS('file.js');`

Comment: so there's not any kind of way to reload the whole javascript, without knowing what function I am working with?

Comment: @JohnFunk Unfortunately.  This loads a new `script`, and you don't even need the function, just copy/paste the body of the function and at the beginning define `script`.